# JQuery mouseover with live() not being detected unless the cursor reenters the element

Tags: jquery

I have an object that onclick receives an active class and its position is animated. If you hover on the object while ".active" then another element (not a child) should appear.

My problem is that, if the cursor does not leave and reenter the element, then the mouseover event isn't fired. You can see a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/KqMQJ/

If you keep your cursor on top of "hello" you will see the problem.
Note: my real constraints prevent me from making "view" a child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the class **before** you animate. I think this works better, as it can show while animating. This requires moving both elements concurrently.

[Source code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdMkX/)

```
$("#whatever").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").mouseover();
    $(this).animate({marginLeft: "50px"});
    $('#view').animate({marginLeft: "50px"});
});
```

Comment: Upvoted because this is the correct answer for most cases, unfortunately in my particular case I can't animate "view".

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you cannot do so?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to animate "view"; it just won't show up correctly within "active" as "active" is animated otherwise. Do you need it to show up in "active" during the transition?

Comment: @Duopixel: Can you check my comments and clarify?

Comment: it's animated with contentflow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/),  once the image reaches the center and the image is hovered I want to display the view div. Don't know how long the image will take to reach the center, and you can't replicate the scaling functions done on the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Call the mouseover handler as soon as you've added the class:

```
$("#whatever").click(function(e) {
    $(this).animate({marginLeft: "50px"}, function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass("active");

        if ($this.offset().left <= e.pageX) {
            $this.mouseover();
        }
    });
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KqMQJ/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this will fire mouseover even if the cursor is not on top of #whatever (on your demo, click on the left edge of the box)

Comment: @Duopixel See my edit.  Note that it only checks whether the mouse is within the left boundary of the box, not the top, right or bottom boundaries; these would not be difficult to add if so desired. [See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KqMQJ/5/).

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case this worked:

```
$("#whatever.active").live('mouseover mouseout mousemove',function(event){
    if (event.type=="mouseover")
        $("#view").css("opacity", "1");
    else
        $("#view").css("opacity", "0");
    }
);
```

However, I'm accepting Kyle's answer as it's what applies for most cases.